# Запятая? Доспех с шлемом

Tags: пунктуация

> В зал ворвались воины короля в чёрных доспехах(,) с жуткими шлемами и окровавленными саблями.

Если убрать запятую, то получится «чёрный доспех с жутким шлемом»? Так можно сказать («доспех с шлемом»)? Или обязательно перечисление («в чёрных доспехах, с жуткими шлемами, с окровавленными саблями»)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. С точки зрения грамматики и интонации, оба варианта нехороши: они сложно читаются и понимаются.
2. Можно предложить следующий вариант: "В зал ворвались воины короля, в чёрных доспехах с жуткими шлемами, с окровавленными саблями". Или как-то еще доработать предложение, но это надо смотреть по тексту. Можно при обособлении поставить тире.
3. Вопрос о принципиальном включении шлема в доспехи здесь не важен, но важно единое сочетание (союз С): "черные доспехи с жуткими шлемами".

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Словарная статья определяет доспехи как боевое снаряжение, вооружение воина.  (Корень СПЕХ  в данном случае имеет значение «помогать», отошедшее в современном языке на второй план). Это самое общее значение доспехов.

Сужая это понятие, под доспехами мы можем понимать всё ЗАЩИНОЕ снаряжение, а также можно разделить его на шлем и доспехи, например: «Шлем и доспехи рыцарей короля Артура».

Answer (score 1):

Шлем в понятие "доспехи" вполне входит, поэтому запятая здесь не нужна. Доспехи без шлема можно назвать "латы" или "кольчуга". Еще нужно отметить, что правильно не *с шлемом*, а *с**о** шлемом*, так как иначе фразу сложно произнести.

Answer (score 0):

Если иметь в виду, что доспехи - это защитная одежда, панцирь воина, то понятно, что шлем в понятие "доспехи" не входит, следовательно, в приведенном Вами предложении идет перечисление того, во что были облачены воины, то есть запятая после слова "доспехи" вполне мотивирована.

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант такой.

В зал ворвались воины короля, в чёрных доспехах, с жуткими шлемами, с окровавленными саблями.

Здесь обособляется несогласованное определение, выраженное сущ. с предлогами. По Розенталю, такое обособление происходит, если подчеркивается выражаемое ими значение.
Его пример таков. Офицеры, в новых сюртуках, белых перчатках и блестящих эполетах, щеголяли по улицам и бульвару.